# Why can't I edit any post?

Tags: support, bug, editing

I currently have 103 reputation in Physics Stack Exchange but why there is no any edit option under the posts. In other stack exchange websites it appears very well and I can edit any post and the edits are applied when it is peer reviewed. But this problem is happening with me in this Physics Stack Exchange. Why?? 
Any answer regarding this problem will be appreciated by me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It [appears](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/147585/sgrmshrsm7?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), as of now, that seven of your eight suggested edits have been rejected by reviewers.  And looking through the list, I agree: they're all reasonable changes, but too trivial to warrant bumping a post to the front page.

Your inability to suggest new edits is temporary and will return in a few days.

Comment: Thanks sir, In how many days this ability will return back?

Comment: It looks like [seven days from your most recent rejected edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91392/280545).